# Displaying item tags in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-cursor

Im kind of stuck with a problem that seemed easy at the beginning. I want to display items in a ListView that support multiple tags. I have set up a CursorAdapter to supply my ListView with the necessary data but I'm not quite sure what the best way would be to get this working.

By using JOINs I've extracted the items and tags from the database.

```
item1 | tagA
item1 | tagB
item2 | tagC
item3 | tagB
```

I've tried a lot of junk, but that's all it was until now... junk.

Eventough the first two items share the exact same `_id` field, the items are assigned to seperate ListViews, I guess that has to do with the fact that the Adapter generates a new list item for every entry in the Cursor. Somewhere I was hoping that it would try to update list entries with the same `_id` which would leave me with a simple solution of just writing the code in the ViewBinder to append to the tag View any time `setViewValue()` would be called.

1. I've considered manually executing `Cursor.moveToNext()` in the ViewBinder to add the necessary tag TextViews to my ListView if the id's of subsequent Cursors match. This would not completely solve my problem as the cursor of the actual ListView wouldn't be affected by the `moveToNext()` call in the ViewBinder (due to the whole pass-by-value thing with arguments). The first item in the List does display all the tags `item1 | tagA, tagB`, but the next Cursor still displays the already displayed `item1` in `item1 | tagB` as the Cursor of the adapter can't be altered by the ViewBinder call.
2. I've considered writing/extending objects and having my Adapter connect the dots (.e.g.: I pass the adapter `List<Item>` (instead of a Cursor) and arm `Item` with method `public List<String> getTags()` to easily extract the tags per item. 
       List { 
         Item { id=1, tags={tagA, tagB } },
         Item { id=2, tags={tagC} },
         Item { id=3, tags={tagB} }
       }
   I would iterate through the Cursor set to populate the List. However, to do this I really need to know the understand Cursor's housekeeping to keep things clean.

Basically, I don't wanna come up with a dirty solution. I bet some of you have already tackled this problem somewhere in the past. What is the best way to approach this problem?